# JAR file does not access the internet

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar, jar-signing

I have a program that accesses the internet using JSOUP. The program works fine when inside NetBeans but as soon as I build the project and run the jar file outside of NetBeans, the processing that requires internet does not work. The jar file does not close, everything else including the database, sending emails, navigating etc all works fine.

```
doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(searchURL).timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.52")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").followRedirects(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
```

is this problem related to the jar file being unsigned? I have tried using Java Web Start in NetBeans but it always unticks itself.

Comment: What do you mean by Doesn't work? Have you waited for `timeout`? Possibly NetBeans have proxy set as an environment variable so you might need to do the same in your code yourself.

Comment: The application will not access the internet or any services that require the internet. Yes I have waited for the timeout, but still nothing happens. Could the Proxy really be the issue here?

Comment: Depends on how the network is set up. In some cases http and https proxies are needed to access external resources.